# Collision Detection not working with two lists of objects?

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

My collision detection doesn't work. I have a list for my projectile and another for my block. I tried to use a loop to detect collision detection as shown in my code but its not working. My code for collision detection is:

```
public void Collision_Detection()
    {
     for (int p = 0; p < projectile.Count; p++)
        {
         for (int i = 0; i < level_1.Count; i++)
            {

             if (projectile_obj[p].logRect.Intersects(level_1_blocks[i].rectangle))
               {
                //Subprogram here          
               }
          }
     }
}
```

My projectile class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;


namespace DestroytheFort
{

 class Projectile 
{
    public static Texture2D log;
    public static Vector2 logPos;
    public Rectangle logRect;

    public Projectile(Texture2D newLog, Vector2 newLogPos, Rectangle newLogRect)
    {
        log = newLog;
        logPos = newLogPos;
        logRect = newLogRect;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
    }



    static double g = 520;
    public static int keyState = 0;
    static double v, vx, vy, alpha, t2 = 0;

    public static void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // TODO: Add your update code here
        if ((ISU.mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) && ISU.isInLevel == true)
        {
            keyState = 1;
            v = -820;
            alpha = MathHelper.ToRadians(33f);
            vx = v * Math.Cos(alpha);
            vy = v * Math.Sin(alpha);
        }
        if (keyState == 1)
        {
            logPos.Y = (float)(vy * t2 + g * t2 * t2 / 2) + 540 - log.Height;
            logPos.X = (float)((vx * -1) * t2) + 60;
            t2 = t2 + gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }
        if (logPos.Y > ISU.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - log.Height)
        {
            logPos.Y = ISU.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - log.Height;
            keyState = 0;
            t2 = 0;
        }
        if (logPos.X > ISU.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - log.Width)
        {
            logPos.X = ISU.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - log.Width;
            keyState = 0;
            t2 = 0;
        }
  }
   public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

        spriteBatch.Draw(log, logPos, logRect, Color.White); 

    }
}
```

And my level_1 class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace DestroytheFort
{

class Wood_Level_1
{
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Rectangle rectangle;


    public Wood_Level_1(Texture2D newTexture, Rectangle newRect)
    {
        texture = newTexture;
        rectangle = newRect;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game component to perform any initialization it needs to before starting
    /// to run.  This is where it can query for any required services and load content.
    /// </summary>
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization code here


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game component to update itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // TODO: Add your update code here


    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, Color.White);
    }
 }
```

}

level_1 is the name of the list for my Level 1 class. I call the Collision Detection method in Update() in my main class. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is badly formatted. Several trailing curly braces are missing. Please update it. Fix your question and I'll be happy to answer it.

Comment: Thanks will do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're comparing the texture subrects, not the object's bounds. `Projectile.logRect` and `Wood_Level_1.rectangle` are the texture subrects, which you use for both collision detection and drawing. You need to store and update the current positions of each object so you can check their bounds in the world.

```
class Projectile
{
    // Removed 'static' and renamed from 'log' and 'logRect', as static limits
    // instancing and a class called "Projectile" shouldn't be limited to logs.
    public Texture2D texture;
    public Rectangle srcRect;
    public Vector2 position;
    // I suggest moving this to your input system. It's out of place here.
    public static int keyState; // = 0 is the default.

    public Projectile(Texture2D texture, Rectangle srcRect, Vector2 position)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.srcRect = srcRect;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // You use static variables where locals will suffice.
        double v = 0;
        double vx = 0, vy = 0;
        double alpha = 0;
        double t2 = 0;

        // I haven't thoroughly analyzed your math, but assuming it's correct, bounds should be computed correctly.
        if ((ISU.mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) && ISU.isInLevel == true)
        {
            keyState = 1;
            v = -820;
            alpha = MathHelper.ToRadians(33f);
            vx = v * Math.Cos(alpha);
            vy = v * Math.Sin(alpha);
        }

        if (keyState == 1)
        {
            position.Y = (float)(vy * t2 + g * t2 * t2 / 2) + 540 - srcRect.Height;
            position.X = (float)((vx * -1) * t2) + 60;
            t2 = t2 + gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
        }

        // Clamp to the left of the viewport.
        if (position.X < 0) 
        {
            position.X = 0;
            keyState = 0;
        }
        // Clamp to the right of the viewport.
        var right = ISU.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width - srcRect.Width;
        if (position.X > right)
        {
            position.X = right;
            keyState = 0;
        }
        // Clamp to the top of the viewport.
        if (position.Y < 0) 
        {
            position.Y = 0;
            keyState = 0;
        }
        // Clamp to the bottom of the viewport.
        var bottom = ISU.graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height - srcRect.Height;
        if (position.Y > bottom)
        {
            position.Y = bottom;
            keyState = 0;
        }
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, srcRect, Color.White);
    }
}
```

Finally, in the innermost loop of `Collision_Detection`:

```
var proj = projectile_obj[p];
var projBounds = new Rectangle(
    proj.position.X, proj.position.Y,
    proj.srcRect.Width, proj.srcRect.Height);
if (projBounds.Intersects(level_1_blocks[i].rectangle))
{
    //Subprogram here          
}
```

I suggest renaming `Wood_Level_1` to `Level`, so it doesn't appear limited to your first level. If you're not going to do that, at least rename it to `WoodLevel1` to be consistent with .NET conventions.

Comment: What does rect mean? When I try adding it, it says the type doesnt exist

Comment: And if i put one of my classes instead of rect, the Intersects method doesnt work

Comment: "rect" is variable naming shorthand for `Rectangle`. Where are you using "rect" as a type?

Comment: Well I did that. Turns out I had to change the position variables to ints

Comment: position is a `Vector2` so it can hold both a horizontal and vertical axis value. Using `int` for it prevents sub-pixel positioning and limits you to one axis.

Comment: @yathusanthulasi I realized what you were referring to. Apparently I mistakenly typed `Rect` instead of `Rectangle`, and casted each `position` component to `int`. I've since corrected it. It should work correctly now assuming `level_1_blocks[i].rectangle` is a `Rectangle`.